# Exact date and time format of DateTimePicker

Tags: c#, format, globalization, datetimepicker

According to [this article](http://support.microsoft.com/Default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;889834&x=18&y=19) I know, that DateTimePicker control does not reflect **CurrentUICulture**
So, how can I get the *real* culture it's using? I need that to get the string value of DateTimePicker in multi-language application, but in *exactly* the same format as user sees on form (and no, I can't set "hardcode" custom formatting).

**Example:**
When I'm working on Windows with my native Polish settings, then for LongTime it's: **HH:mm:ss** and time in DateTimePicker is displayed like: **09:26:50**

Now, when I want to select different language in my application and change culture settings to *US* in form's constructor:

```
...
System.Globalization.CultureInfo ci = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US");
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = ci;
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = ci;

InitializeComponent();
....
```

then

```
MessageBox.Show(System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.LongTimePattern);
```

shows, that new time format is: **h:mm:ss tt**, yet DateTimePicker still is displaying: **09:26:50**

When I try to get the time string like:

```
dateTimePicker1.Value.ToLongTimeString()
```

or

```
dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString(System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.LongTimePattern)
```

then time is displayed like: **9:26:50 AM**

So my question is - how can I either know, that DateTimePicker is still using system's CultureInfo("pl-PL") or that it's display format is: HH:mm:ss ?

Comment: Try to move your code that set culture to InitializeCulture (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.initializeculture%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). Did you check you cultures before get time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DateTimePicker is a native Windows control.  It uses the time format as configured in the Control Panel + Region and Language applet.  Which looks like this on my machine (I live in the USA):

[image]

So one way you can find out what format it uses is by storing the Thread.CurrentCulture value *before you change it*.

Do note that changing the culture of the UI thread is a pretty dangerous thing to do.  The problem is that any other thread in your program, especially little thread-pool and I/O completion threads, still run with the machine's default culture, as configured in the Administrative tab in the above screenshot.  That can cause subtle bugs that are hard to find.  Like a SortedList created on the UI thread that suddenly isn't sorted anymore in the worker thread.  .NET 4.5 will provide a fix for this problem with the added CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture and DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture properties.

Rest assured that few users of your program will actually wish to run it in a language that doesn't match their machine setting and mother tongue.  Providing a language change option in your UI is a demo feature, it doesn't actually get used.

Comment: That's something for start... However, I need that in a class in .dll, that is going to be attached to other projects, so I'm afraid I don't have access to the place where language is changed. Unless I force its user to provide the "default" culture to the class - that's some solution. Best if I could somehow "bypass" .NET culture and get to the one which is set in Control Panel...

Comment: Well, you could take advantage of the Big Problem I warned you about.  Start a little helper thread, it's Culture will be the system default.  Beats pinvoking GetSystemDefaultLCID :)

Comment: That's great advice. But if you start a helper thread, are you sure it won't inherit the culture of the thread which created it? Also a pinvoke (by the way, on Vista/W2K8 there is also GetSystemDefaultLocaleName) seems simpler than the multithreading approach, in my humble opinion.

Comment: @Clafou - No, if that would work then I wouldn't have warned about the Big Problem. Culture doesn't flow in the Thread.ExecutionContext